# Macro to merge cells from two columns

Tags: excel, merge, vba

I would like to create a macro that merges cells in column A with the cell in column B only if there is data in column A.  Please help

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?
I assumed that columns A and B are filled and I concatenated values from cells A and B in cell A.

```
Sub concatenate()
Dim row As Integer
Range("A1").Select
row = 0
Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(row, 0).Value = ""
    ActiveCell.Offset(row, 0).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(row, 0).Value + ActiveCell.Offset(row, 1).Value
    row = row + 1
Loop
End Sub
```